# Android: Is it possible to link two full screen fragments to one activity (useing just one, but choose the right one with logic)?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I got a idea yesterday and I wanted to ask you if this is working and how.
So I use a form to get user input and safe it into a database.
I use a activity for this task:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZMOi.png
Now I want to add another task with the same layout, but a different logic.
The user should be able to edit the data (same layout, but editing the information in database instead of creating a new object).

My idea:
A `DataActivity` should open, when the user wants to start the create or edit function.
The `DataActivity` holds two full screen fragments and should be able to start the right fragment.
Is it possible to link two full screen fragments to one activity?

Comment: I suggest you improve your question,especially try to don’t add a picture, Have a look here => [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following,

Add two buttons, `save` and `edit` with onClickListeners for opening a `save_fragment` and `edit_fragment` and in the `edit_fragment` make sure there's a Spinner which loads the entries off the database into the `edit_fragment`

phew that involves bit of coding

So a better way would be creating the database by using `Room` and in your respective `Dao` you can specify the `replace` conflict strategy for the update method which overrides/updates the old data with new one

```
@Dao
interface YourDao{

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(formData : FormData)
}
```

Check the official docs for more info about [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room#components) and [onConflict Strategies](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/OnConflictStrategy)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This solution sounds good. I´m using `Room`. The Layout of the fragments is the same. Can i use only one fragment but set a if Statement like this?
intent string with information: edit or create and the object, if its edit
String option = intent...;
if(option=="edit"){
(here i use the replace method in DAO)
}if(option == "create"){
(use create method in DAO)
}

Comment: I guess you can, in your entity class use `title` or something as `primarykey` and in the same fragment, just have a  single button calling `insert` from the `dao`. If the object has same `primarykey` it gets updated or else it gets created for the first time

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to your question **"Is it possible to link two full screen fragments to one activity?"** is **YES**, you can attach as many fragments as you want to the same activity, as long as you handle those fragments properly within the host activity.

There are a lot of examples and usages related to this topic out there. I would recommend you to take a look at this guide: https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments so you can take a general idea of how fragments are used.

Below is a **very simple** code example related to the case you mentioned in your question:

**MainActivity.kt**

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        showProperFragment()
    }

    private fun showProperFragment() {

        var fragmentToShow: Fragment

        // todo: modify your condition here to decide whether showing fragment1 or fragment2
        if (true) {
            fragmentToShow = Fragment1.newInstance("something1", "something2")
        } else {
            fragmentToShow = Fragment2.newInstance("something1", "something2")
        }

        val transaction: FragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()

        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentToShow)
        transaction.addToBackStack(null)

        transaction.commit()
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and of course **Fragment1** and **Fragment2** are two example blank fragments.

Comment: thank you for the answer, i will try this solution!